# ISC DHCP: Unsupported device

Tags: dhcp, routing

I am trying to run ISC DHCP on my wlan1mon device which is in monitor mode. But i get error:

```
systemctl status isc-dhcp-server.service
● isc-dhcp-server.service - LSB: DHCP server
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since czw 2015-10-01 09:07:55 UTC; 1min 20s ago
Process: 2767 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

paź 01 08:45:41 kali dhcpd[2657]: Wrote 0 leases to leases file.
paź 01 08:45:41 kali dhcpd[2657]: Unsupported device type 803 for "wlan1mon"
paź 01 08:45:41 kali dhcpd[2657]: 
paź 01 08:45:41 kali dhcpd[2657]: If you think you have received this message due to a bug rather
paź 01 08:45:43 kali isc-dhcp-server[2650]: Starting ISC DHCP server: dhcpdcheck syslog for diagnostic...led!
paź 01 08:45:43 kali isc-dhcp-server[2650]: failed!
paź 01 08:45:43 kali systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
paź 01 08:45:43 kali systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: DHCP server.
paź 01 08:45:43 kali systemd[1]: Unit isc-dhcp-server.service entered failed state.

GNU nano 2.2.6                    Plik: /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf                                                

# Sample /etc/dhcpd.conf
# (add your comments here)
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
option broadcast-address 192.168.10.255;
option routers 192.168.10.254;
option domain-name-servers 192.168.10.1, 192.168.10.2;
option domain-name "mydomain.example";

subnet 192.168.10.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
range 192.168.10.10 192.168.10.100;
range 192.168.10.150 192.168.10.200;
}





GNU nano 2.2.6                   Plik: /etc/network/interfaces                                              

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-ssid "Darmowy Internet"
wpa-psk "*******"

iface wlan1mon inet static
address 192.168.10.0
netmask 255.255.255.0




GNU nano 2.2.6                 Plik: /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server                                           

INTERFACES="wlan1mon"




ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:db:b5:72  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e8:94:f6:26:10:3f  
      inet addr:192.168.1.106  Bcast:255.255.255.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::ea94:f6ff:fe26:103f/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:9496 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:7073 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:885381 (864.6 KiB)  TX bytes:1075319 (1.0 MiB)

wlan1mon  Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr F8-1A-67-09-7C-FE-30-30-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
      inet addr:192.168.10.0  Bcast:192.168.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST NOTRAILERS PROMISC ALLMULTI  MTU:1800  Metric:1
      RX packets:1409554 errors:0 dropped:1403000 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:351968132 (335.6 MiB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Comment: Monitor mode is passive. The device just listens to everything on-air. without sending anything. I wouldn't expect DHCP to be able to bind to such an interface. Would be pretty useless imho anyway. Did you take a look at `syslog`? The error message says so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When device is in monitor mode only "sniff" traffic, do not send anything.
Because of that can not send `dhcp` offer and `dhcp` can not use this interface.

> Monitor mode, or RFMON (Radio Frequency MONitor) mode, allows a
>   computer with a wireless network interface controller (WNIC) to
>   monitor all traffic received from the wireless network. Unlike
>   promiscuous mode, which is also used for packet sniffing, monitor mode
>   allows packets to be captured without having to associate with an
>   access point or ad hoc network first. Monitor mode only applies to
>   wireless networks, while promiscuous mode can be used on both wired
>   and wireless networks. Monitor mode is one of the six modes that
>   802.11 wireless cards can operate in: Master (acting as an access point), Managed (client, also known as station), Ad hoc, Mesh,
>   Repeater, and Monitor mode.

[resource](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_mode)

Comment: Thanks, changing to wlan1 on managed helped to solve it.